# UITableView Cell is not visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell, mbprogresshud

Hi in my project i need to pull data from json and insert into tableview.i have created two cells but its not coming even after a proper outlet connection.i dont know what is the mistake i have done.my tableview and cells are not visible please check my coding below which is also have json call.

```
-(void)WebServiceTopic{

    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *TopicManager=[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFJSONRequestSerializer*serializer=[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content"];
    [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    TopicManager.requestSerializer=serializer;

    NSString *Postlink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Discussions/%@/?categoryid=14",PUBLICURL, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"USERID"]];

    [TopicManager GET:Postlink parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

        NSLog(@"JSON:%@", responseObject);
        NSMutableDictionary *userDict=(NSMutableDictionary *)responseObject;
        TopicArray = (NSMutableArray*)userDict;
        [TopicTable reloadData];

    }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"the failure is %@", error);
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    }];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableView Datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
    if (TopicArray.count==0) {
        return TopicArray.count;
    }
    return TopicArray.count;
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell";
        DiscussTopicCell *cell = (DiscussTopicCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (TopicArray.count>0) {
            NSDictionary *ResDiction = [TopicArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    cell.ActTitle.text = [ResDiction objectForKey:@"Title"];
                    cell.Name.text=[ResDiction objectForKey:@"CreateUserName"];
                    cell.Comment.text=[ResDiction objectForKey:@"CommentCount"];
                    cell.Notes.text=[ResDiction objectForKey:@"Content"];
                    cell.Category.text=[ResDiction objectForKey:@"Category"];
                    cell.Time.text= [ResDiction objectForKey:@"CreateDate"];


            UIView * additionalSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,cell.frame.size.height-3,cell.frame.size.width,3)];
            additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            [cell addSubview:additionalSeparator];
        }

        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
        DiscussTopicCell *cell = (DiscussTopicCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

        NSDictionary *ResDiction = [TopicArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.ActTitle.text = [ResDiction objectForKey:@"Title"];
        cell.Name.text=[ResDiction objectForKey:@"CreateUserName"];
        cell.Comment.text=[ResDiction objectForKey:@"CommentCount"];
        cell.Notes.text=[ResDiction objectForKey:@"Content"];
        cell.Category.text=[ResDiction objectForKey:@"Category"];
        cell.Time.text= [ResDiction objectForKey:@"CreateDate"];

        UIView * additionalSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,cell.frame.size.height-3,cell.frame.size.width,3)];
        additionalSeparator.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        [cell addSubview:additionalSeparator];

        return cell;

    }

}
```

Comment: you must reload tableview which you have commented after getting response.

Comment: i did that but its getting hung up...still now showing

Comment: try to remove (DiscussTopicCell *) at line DiscussTopicCell *cell = (DiscussTopicCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1]; and other.

Comment: Yo need implements the `reloadData()` when to get all data from web services

Comment: No if i remove that you cant call datas which is stored in DiscussTopicCell @Dev.Rk

Answer (score 0):

You must reload the tableview when it pull the data from server then only it shows some data on tableview. Please reload the tableview.

Example code for reference

```
 cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
          cell.Language_label.text=[[lang_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"lang_desc"];

          if (indexPath.row == color_tag)
          {
                cell.Language_label.backgroundColor=[self colorWithHexString:@"FFCA13"];
          }
          else
          {
                 cell.Language_label.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
          }
          return cell;
}
```

Comment: No its not showing even after reloading....my viewcontroller gets hung up if i did that

Comment: i have a doubt! Did you put the identifier for cell in Storyboard or xib?

Comment: yeah two cells with the name Cell and Cell2

Comment: see above code of my customcell for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the cell. Dequeuing a reusable cell returns nil if there is no cell already created and available for use.

```
if(!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```